# SAS DO Loop with Macro

Tags: sas

To begin, this is for a class, i dont like this language. Its simple Do loop to print the square root of numbers. The objective is to replace the value in the do loop with macro variables. Here is my source code:

```
%LET Start_Value = 1;
%LET Stop_Value = 5;

DATA sqrt_table;
DO &Start_Value. TO &Stop_Value.;
  Sqrt_n = SQRT(&Start_Value.);
  OUTPUT;
END;

RUN;

TITLE 'Square root table from 1 to 5';
PROC PRINT DATA = sqrt_table noobs;
RUN;
TITLE;
```

The Log says the error is in the DO &Start_Value. "Symbol is not recognized"
I followed the the source coude given, i have decalred the macros as they should be, and i am accessing them as i read to do so. What is the issue?

Comment: Saying you don't like a language is a great way to ask from help from the users for starters.

Comment: https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2011/09/07/loops-in-sas.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are begginer in SAS don't mix macro lanauge wit 4GL. Here is what you need.

```
%LET Start_Value = 1;
%LET Stop_Value = 5;

DATA sqrt_table;
   DO i = &Start_Value. TO &Stop_Value.;
      Sqrt_n = SQRT(i);
      OUTPUT;
   END;
RUN;
```

Comment: Wonderful, thanks a million. As for the Macros, this is the last unit we are covering in my stats certification before we move on to R. This is what i was instructed to do.

Answer (score 4):

Macro code in general, and in this case specifically, is just used to replace constant text.  First get a working DO loop without any macro variables and then replace the parts that you want to vary with the macro variable references.

So the basic syntax for an iterative DO loop is:

```
do VAR=START to END;
  ...
end;
```

Where `VAR` is a variable name and `start` and `end` are numerical expressions.

Compare that to the pattern of your attempt and you can see that you have left off the `VAR=` part.

Also the assignment statement is going to assign the same value to `SQRT_N` on every iteration of the DO loop.  Because you have essentially written.

```
Sqrt_n = SQRT(1);
```

Remember macro variables are just ways to help you generate the program that you want SAS to actually run.

Comment: I did that, thats how i arrived at the above code and the current compilation error i am asking for help.

Comment: So you fixed the syntax of your `do` loop?  And the assignment statement?  What variable name did you use in the `do` loop? Did you make sure to reference that variable in the `sqrt()` function call?